# Calculate local position of a child point, relative to a rotated parent point

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the global co-ordinates of two points in 2D space. If Point 1 is rotated θ degrees, how can I calculate the position of Point 2 as if it were relative to Point 1 and inside it's rotated co-ordinate system?

I have heard of matrices but I don't understand them!

Answer (score 0):

If $P_1=(x_1, y_1)$, $P_2=(x_2, y_2)$ and $\theta$ is the rotation angle, then

$
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 \\
    y_1
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
    \sin \theta & \cos  \theta
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_2 - x_1 \\
    y_2 - y_1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    x'_2 \\
    y'_2
\end{bmatrix}
$

where $P'_2=(x'_2, y'_2)$ is $P_2$ rotated(counterclockwise if $\theta>0$) around $P_1$ by $\theta$ radians.

Comment: Thanks for this, though I don't think it's quite what I was after because the output of P2 is not affected by P1's X and Y at all, which it should be.

As an example, if P1 is [0,0] and P2 is [10,10], and theta (rotation around P1) is 45º. The local position of P2 relative to P1 would be [14.1421,0]. If P1 were [5,5] instead, the output should be [7.0711,0]

I might add that I am dealing in a global space with an inverted Y axis .

Comment: @kitkats I made an edit. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hey, thanks. I don't think this is what I meant, though because I'm not great with matrices I can't be sure. Anyway, a friend helped me figure it out and it looks like this: [p2(x)- p1(x)*Math.cos(theta) + p2(y)- p1(y)*Math.sin(theta), -p2(x)- p1(x)*Math.sin(theta) + p2(y)- p1(y)*Math.cos(theta)] (Apologies for the notational unconventionality)